# ADF CDM Source Transformation not reading data

Tags: azure-data-factory, common-data-service

I am having an issue with the inline data set for Common Data Model in Azure Data Factory.
Simply, everything in ADF appears to connect and read from my manifest file and entity definition - but when I click the "Data preview" button, I always get "No output data" - which I find bizarre, as the data can be read perfectly when using the CDM connector to the same files in PowerBI. What am I doing wrong to mean that the data is not read into the data preview and subsequent transformations in the mapping data flow?

My Manifest file looks as below (referring to an example entity):

```
{
    "$schema": "CdmManifest.cdm.json",
    "jsonSchemaSemanticVersion": "1.0.0",
    "imports": [
        {
            "corpusPath": "cdm:/foundations.cdm.json"
        }
    ],
    "manifestName": "manifestExample",
    "explanation": "example",
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "LocalEntity",
            "entityName": "Entityname",
            "entityPath": "folder/EntityName.cdm.json/Entityname",
            "dataPartitions": [
                {
                    "location": "folder/data/Entityname/Entityname.csv",
                    "exhibitsTraits": [
                        {
                            "traitReference": "is.partition.format.CSV",
                            "arguments": [
                                {
                                    "name": "columnHeaders",
                                    "value": "true"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "delimiter",
                                    "value": ","
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
...
```

Comment: Can you ensure that your ADLS Gen2 path above to your data "folder/data/Entityname/Entityname.csv" is correct? Also, are you hitting "data preview" in the Source or Sink?

Comment: Hi @MadDog, have you check this settings as Mark said? Did you solve it now?

Comment: The path is definitely correct (as, I believe, is proven by it being visible through the PowerBI CDM data connector) and the check is in the data preview for the Source transformation.

Comment: if not already clear, I'm using the Manifest (not Model) metadata format.

Comment: Same message. Now it's work with an export not to a blob storage but to a data lake storage gen 2.

Answer (score 0):

I am having exactly same output message "No output data". I am using json not manifest. If i sink the source it moves no data but without error. My CDM originates from PowerBI dataflow. The PowerApps works fine but historization and privileges make it useless.

Edit:
On Microsofts info on preview feature we can find this
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8SGd.png). I will make a guess that CDM the ADS sources is not the same which orignates from Power BI.